# What does this "Will do" response mean exactly?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Me, per email, one hour ago:

> Hello,
>   I am available in an hour for the following three hours.
>   Just drop me an email when you are available and I will send you a meeting invite.

Him, per email, right now:

> Will do.

Does this mean that he is available right now and that I should open an online meeting invite, or am I understanding correctly that he will send me an email later when he is really available?

Comment: As an American, I would interpret this as an acknowledgement of your request/instruction, and thus that he will send an email when he is available.

Comment: You asked him to drop you an e-mail when he's available - he said in abbreviated form "I will do that".